# CSS / Javascript - how to place a nextParticle image in the centre of a screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a codepen demo using a particle-slider effect on a logo image and I can't seem to apply any styling rules to the image at all. I'm attempting to centralise the image, at the moment its stuck on the left and I can't get it to move. I've tried a few different angles but nothing. This is the [link](https://codepen.io/MikeWhitehead/pen/Mryzmg)

**HTML**

```
<body>  
        <img id="logo" class="next-particle"  data-init-position="random"
                  data-init-direction="left"
                  data-fade-position="left"
                  data-fade-direction="left"

                  data-particle-gap="1"

                 data-width="800"
                  data-height="600"

                  data-max-width="700"
                  data-max-height="500"



                  data-mouse-force="80"

                   data-gravity="0.06"

                   data-noise="20"

                 src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1513726195/XBD1_dqjlw5.png">

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

#logo img {
 position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: add text-align: center to body, remove styiling from image...https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXNEmZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add align='center' to html tag

```
<html align='center'>
<head>
</head>
<style>
body {
  position: relative;
}

#logo img {
 position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
</style>
<body>  
        <img id="logo" class="next-particle"  data-init-position="random"
                  data-init-direction="left"
                  data-fade-position="left"
                  data-fade-direction="left"

                  data-particle-gap="1"

                 data-width="800"
                  data-height="600"

                  data-max-width="700"
                  data-max-height="500"



                  data-mouse-force="80"

                   data-gravity="0.06"

                   data-noise="20"

                 src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1513726195/XBD1_dqjlw5.png">

</body>
</html>
```

[image]